# filepath.Walk() returned 0xc08402f180

Tags: go, goroutine

I am new to the Go language and trying to learn.

I made a program to walk through a directory. It worked fine but when I try to run the program in a go routine it returns:

> filepath.Walk() returned 0xc08402f180

my function is this:

```
func LoadData(root string) {
    runtime.GOMAXPROCS(runtime.NumCPU())
    c := make(chan error)
    go func() {c<-filepath.Walk(root, WalkFunc)}()
    if erw := c; erw != nil {
        fmt.Printf("filepath.Walk() returned %v\n", erw)
    // log.Fatal(erw)
    }
}
```

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Do not `runtime.GOMAXPROCS(runtime.NumCPU())` this is just cult.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are printing the channel, not the return from the channel.  Try this

```
if erw := <-c; erw != nil {
    fmt.Printf("filepath.Walk() returned %v\n", erw)
//  log.Fatal(erw)
}
```